# SimpleXml Accessing attributes

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I am trying to access an attribute using simplXML

Here is an example of my XML format:

```
<xml>
    <config>
        <anothernode></anothernode>
        <anothernode></anothernode>
        <anothernode></anothernode>
        <anothernode></anothernode>
        <anothernode></anothernode>
        <popup name="rory" type="y" />
        <popup name="joe" type="z" />
        <popup name="pat" type="u" />
        <popup name="mary" type="v" />
    </config>
</xml>
```

This echos out the first popup name i.e "Rory":

```
echo "exported: " . $xml->config->popup['name'] . "<br >";
```

This echos out the first type i.e "y"

```
echo "exported: " . $xml->config->popup['type'] . "<br >";
```

Im trying to loop through all of them and get all the values so ill have something like this

Rory - y
Joe - z
Pat -u
Mary - v

My crappy attempt is something like this below but that nor a ton of other variations i tried worked either, im just starting to learn simpleXML and havent quite got my head around it.

```
foreach($xml->config->popup['name'] as $node => $key){
    //
    echo $node . " - ". $xml->config->popup['$key']['type'] . "<br />";
    }
```

Now if the xml was structured better and the popup element was under a main popups element i could use the children() option to cycle through each popup and access it but this unusual format in the XML im working on doesnt seem to have any examples on the internet i can find that can tell me how to access them in a foreach loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop on the `popup` nodes, eg

```
foreach ($xml->config->popup as $popup) {
    echo $popup['name'], ' - ', $popup['type'], '<br>';
}
```

Demo - http://codepad.viper-7.com/HElyiA (I also fixed your XML)